# HTML-ошибка команды отключения кэширования

Tags: html, кэширование

Валидатор HTML-кода показывает ошибку, пожалуйста помогите исправить. Было 25 ошибок, откорректировал до одной, а вот это ума не приложу чем не нравится валидатору.  ([validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fshveypokrov.ru%2F))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В HTML5 очень малый набор значений, доступных для `http-equiv`, полный список можно увидеть [здесь](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names), пункт 4.2.5.3, необходимо с сервера отправлять заголовки в HTTP ответе, а как именно - уже зависит от вашего сервера и это отдельный вопрос. Надеюсь помог)